# Is it possible to make text message = command with slash? Telegram python bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I created telegram bot and now it's using commands through commandhandler with slash to activate different functions, but the question is - Is it possible to make him understand that text = /command, for example ("yes, Y, Yes, YES" = /yes).

I want to keep my commandhandlers, but want to make keyboard buttons with commands without slashes.

```
self._keyboard: List[List[Union[str, KeyboardButton]]] = [
                                   ['/yes', '/no', '/sure'],
                                   ['/absolutely', '/allright'],


handles = [
CommandHandler('yes', self._yes),
CommandHandler('no', self._no),
CommandHandler('sure', self._sure),
CommandHandler('absolutely', self._absolutely),
CommandHandler('allright', self._allright),

#New added string: (Big Thanks to the user CallMeStag)
MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^yes$'), self._yes),
]



#I can start bot, bot not every function working, under is error which i got:
AttributeError: MessageHandler object has no attribute command
```

Comment: It is hard to answer this question without seeing how you are implementing your commands. Please post a relevant portion of your code so others can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`KeyboardButtons`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton) are just shortcuts for sending a message with the text that they show. You can't make them send a different text.
What you *can* do is to simply handle non-command messages as well. If you receive a message with the text `yes`/`Y`/`Yes`/`YES`, just run the same code that you would run for `/yes`.

**EDIT**: With `python-telegram-bot`, you can do this with [`MessageHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.messagehandler.html) and e.g. [`Filters.regex`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.regex):

```
MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^yes|Y|Yes|YES$'), self._yes)
```

Comment: Its exactly what i want to do, but cant understand right way to write it in the code. Exactly i want to make bot run the same code with for example (/yes) text message and (yes/Y/Yes/YES) text message. Can you show code example? It will help me a lot to understand. Thanks :)

Comment: I found a way to write right argument, thanks a lot for your help :)